# Trying to add a fragment inside an adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tried to add a fragment on button click action inside an adapter which extends a BaseAdapter.
But to use fragments the class has to extend Fragment to use the FragmentManager.
I've imported :

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

But still facing an error here:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
```

I've also tried to give the activity reference when getting the FragmentManager,it gave more errors.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my adapter code:
Drawer item(view) onclick action:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (position == 1)// Home
                        {


                        Home2Fragment fragment = new Home2Fragment();
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                                    .beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.add(fragment, null);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();

                        }

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

Because importing Fragments from support library so, use `getSupportFragmentManager` method to get `FragmentManager` :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager=<Activity_Context>.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Need to use `FragmentActivity` context to access `FragmentManager` and also make sure extending `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Comment: Tried that too..still did not work.Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @VinayPandravada : see my answer

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K :  tried giving that too bro..its asking to change my fragment to android.app.fragment which effects my code below

Answer (score 0):

It is considered good practice to use let Adapters be an inner class of the List that uses them. That gives the adapter full access to the class using them and if it's a fragment, you can use the fragment manager.